# ajax undefined after a thousand iterations

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

When creating an animation I try to use `javascript` for additional effects, namely snow being piled up and falling off the edges of the foreground. I figured that the `javascript` could do the "calculations" on a `<canvas>` that had the image, then send the "snow" to a `php` script that would create the `png` images. This is all placed on my local "server" because that is the only one that can write files.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Making Snow</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
<canvas id="canvas" width="1920px" height="1080px"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    var frame=-530;
    var simg = new Image()
    var dimg = new Image()
    onload = function()
    {
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        simg.src = "prodB/C/DGB.0530.png"
    }
    simg.onload = function()
    {
        var ipo=3;
        // Initialize all pixels on the screen/page
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(simg,0,0);
        document.title = "Making Snow " + (frame+530) + " / 7000";
        snowdraw();
    }
    dimg.onerror = function()
    {
        dimg.src = "../imagewriting/snow" + zeroFill(frame+530,4) + ".png";
    }
    dimg.onload = function()
    {
        frame++;
        if(frame<530)
            simg.src = "prodB/C/DGB.0530.png"
        else if(frame>4400)
            simg.src = "prodB/C/DGB.4400.png"
        else
            simg.src = "prodB/C/DGB." + zeroFill(frame,4) + ".png"
    }
    var snowdraw = function()
    {
            var temp;
            var canvasData = "";
//          console.log(screen);
            // Animation
            // Choose a random pixel at the top of the screen
            if(frame<7000)
            {
                for(ny=canvas.height-2; ny>=0; ny--)
                {   // Iterate through all the pixels starting from the bottom right corner.
                    for(nx=canvas.width-2; nx>=0; nx--)
                    {
                        canvasData=canvasData+"1";
                    }
                }
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "makesnow.php",
                    data:{ imgData: canvasData, frame: (frame+530)  }
                    })
                    .done(function( msg ) {
                        dimg.src = "../imagewriting/snow" + zeroFill(frame+530,4) + ".png";
                    });
            }
            else
            {
                document.title = "COMPLETE";
            }
    }

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript
// by Peter Bailey http://stackoverflow.com/users/8815
function zeroFill( number, width )
{
  width -= number.toString().length;
  if ( width > 0 )
  {
    return new Array( width + (/\./.test( number ) ? 2 : 1) ).join( '0' ) + number;
  }
  return number + ""; // always return a string
}
</script>

</html>
```

However, on the 1640th frame (or more precisely `frame=1110`) ajax is suddenly undefined. The image `snow1640.png` is created, but the browser tells me `ajax is not defined` and won't advance passed `Making Snow 1640 / 7000`. Because of the small random nature for each "snow flake" I can't just pick it up from where I left off, as the snow would jump from one frame to the next. Though I did try that at one point and ajax still stopped after that frame.

I first ran it on the local machine running Firefox (`http://127.0.0.1/...`) then moved onto another machine on the network which is more powerful running Chrome and both died on that same frame. Thought it might be a memory or file limit so I moved the complete frames out of there. Still nothing.

EDIT: Code now snippit of just the problem.

Also, `console.log` for `data` and `ajax.responseText` seem to be generally empty, both during successful "renders" and when it starts iterating `ajax is not defined` (every other line empty, every other error).

EDIT: New development! Turns out that the error `ReferenceError: ajax is not defined` anyways gets called between frames (and the 404 when asking `dimg` if image was created).

EDIT: By typing in `console.log($.ajax)` after `onload` and commenting out `simg.src` I got `function ajax()`.

Error persists, this time I expanded it to reveal the following:

```
success    http://127.0.0.1/ag/makesnowBC.html 197:7
j          http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js 2:27131
fireWith   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js 2:27949
x          http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js 4:22242
b          http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js 4:26298
```

EDIT: Changed the code to now use Synchronous ajax. This time there are no error messages what so ever, but it still stops at 1640.

Comment: A lot of code to go through. Can you condense this into a working snippet for a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: and does it work for smaller farmes? and what does the `console.logs` say?

Comment: @Edwin Console.logs are quite empty... Blank breaks in the console between the 404 and ReferenceError.

Comment: it's a little bit hard to follow you :), can you update your jquery to a newer one? and do you say anything if you do: `console.log($.ajax);`?

Comment: @Edwin Is there a newer version than the one at ajax.googleapis.com? Because that is where I'm loading those references from directly. No local copies.

Comment: Although it is not a good practice, have you tried what happens, if you make the AJAX Synchronous ?  (Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.)

Comment: just a comment: it looks like you are stressing the net / the server for just an effect, think about moving the logic to the client

Comment: @halfbit Like I said, I did try running this on the local server and another computer on the network. You think I should run this from work? Also, I looked up synchronous ajax and implemented that. This time no repeat ReferenceErrors, however it still stopped at 1640, and not a single error message on that.

Comment: I like errors like this: I suggest to try: stay Synchronous, download only the same picture || download an empty or no picture || don't draw the canvas || don't clear it || take a new canvas with every pic

Comment: what do you see in network debugger?

Comment: @halfbit Having a look on the `Network` tab from the remote computer reveals the following: `200  GET  DGB.1111.png  192.168.1...  js img  png  ---  0 B` ... 200 does mean successful, right?

Comment: 200 - ok, but 0 B? is what you expect?

Comment: Hm... No... ... ¤facepalm¤ Well, the file DOES exist, but is it a valid image? javascript needs a "verbose" flag.